# Can't create another worklight 6.1 hybrid app after the project is connected to TFS

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

We have created a worklight project, with a hybrid app, an Android enviroment and a couple of sql adapters. We have added the project to Team Foundation Server (TFS), but after that we cannot add another hybrid app. The project name dropdown is empty. This also goes for inner application, while all the other worklight compononents seems to be working fine, with the project I want appearing in the dropdown.

I do suspect it might be related to some kind of lock on some files, but I can't figure out which ones.

Steps:

1. Create an hybrid app in Worklight
2. Add the Android environment
3. Add it to TFS, excluded native folder, .classpath and org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs

Comment: And if you disconnect from TFS, you are then able to add another application to the existing project?

Comment: It is the same. But if I try adding without putting in a project that works ok. If I add another project (not connected to TFS) that project appears in the dropdown. After that I can't add apps to the old project anymore.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand... either try rephrasing or edit the question with full reproduction step-by-step.

Comment: Based on the added steps to the questions - why do you exclude the native folder, .classpath and org.... what happens if you don't?

Answer (score 0):

The official word is that IBM Worklight does not support Microsoft TFS. So if it works - great, if it doesn't - not so great, but nothing can be done until and if it is supported.

What you can do:

1. Submit a feature request: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/connect.html
2. Try IBM RTC instead? or other-like products that may work.